# How Do I create an admin panel of my website? specially using bootstrap templets

Tags: templates, admin, panel

I am trying to create an only admin accessible who can change only the content of the website. I saw some suggestions online saying that bootstrap is the easier way of applying the admin panel But I do not know if Bootstrap Admin Dashboard Templates will help me change my content of a website. Also, I admin panel accessible from my own websites such as www.xyz.com/admin or administrator. If it does that what is the procedure of applying the bootstrap can someone please upload a link that I can learn from. 
Because  I am working for an employee who will in need to update the news/ information content and so many other things. SO please someone help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Forest Admin](https://www.forestadmin.com). In a few minutes, you can generate an admin panel application from your database where your content is stored.

Applying a template will not help you build your admin panel entirely. It's just a frontend-helper tool.

Comment: So with this tool I will be able to create my website based on HTML CSS, JAVAscript and than for the client to do all the updating he can use forest Admin?

Comment: Exactly. In other words, you can focus on building your website and use Forest Admin to let your customer be autonomous on admin operations.